# Is 'load' command in spark an action or transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
df = spark.read.format('csv').load('...')
```

It is my understanding that , load is a transformation and executes only when an action is called. However, while the load statement is being executed, it appears to be an action under the Spark UI.

Edit:

From the comments/answers , i inferred that load may or may not be a transformation but **not** definitely an action which is great and understandable.

If it is not an action why it is creating a DAG? 
It creates a DAG just for a load statement not just WholeStageCodegen(which is in SQL tab). 
Please see the below image: 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZEW3.png)

Comment: It is a transformation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818629/what-does-load-do-in-spark

Comment: Thank you for the response. I see from the shared link, that it is a transformation and take some time to execute because it does metadata checks and all.
My another question stills stands unanswered. Why a simple load statement is creating a DAG , which should not happen.

Comment: The thing under UI is simply wholeStageCodegen, not an Action. Your question is not that specific in relation to your comment. I grant you nit is a little fuzzy. See the link's approved answer, it is also vague though.

Comment: You should  ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, based on your comments:

> Load does nothing. It is just part of the sqlContext.read or
>   spark.read.format API as a parameter, that can be set indirectly or
>   directly on the read. read allows data formats to be specified.

The DF or underlying RDD is evaluated lazily as they say.

Answer (score 0):

Load is neither action nor transformation it is a method of class DataFrameReader
that describes how to load data from an external data source.

All methods of DataFrameReader merely describe a process of loading a data and do not trigger a Spark job (until an action is called).

This is mentioned by jaceklaskowski Please read https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-DataFrameReader.html#methods

you can also refer the transformation and action API list from the databricks here
https://training.databricks.com/visualapi.pdf load is not mentioned anywhere as a transformation or action